# Hex-binning Geospatial Data

Tags: python, geospatial

*Okay, I feel like this maybe a very easy to answer for many of you. If you feel tempted to downvote this question, please know I tried earnestly for a dozen hours to find what I think should have been an easy answer, yet could not find it because perhaps that's how new I am to data science and data-related Python packages.*

I have simple lat-long coordinates that I would like to hex-bin. I see this in so many programs, including kepler.gl, matlab, d3 etc, but instead of seeing a *visualization* of the bins, I just want to have the bin count in tabular form (to then visualize elsewhere):

For example, maybe it's a simple function that takes in a list of lat-long pairs and a radius, which returns a dataset like the following:

| Hex Center Lat | Hex Center Long | Bin Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 40.525 | 70.426 | 26 |
| ... | ... | ... |

I'm specifically looking for a Python-language answer.

#### What I've tried so far

(I've tried to explain my specific problems at the end of this code block)

```py
# https://towardsdatascience.com/geobinning-starbucks-88bc636f43c6

import numpy as np  # linear algebra
import pandas as pd  # data processing, CSV file I/O (e.g. pd.read_csv)
import geobinning as gb
import geopandas as gpd
import pyogrio

# Here is where I read in the raw geo coordinate data
potholes = pd.read_csv('./data.csv')

# extract coordinates
points = []
for i, d in potholes.iterrows():
  points.append([d['Y'], d['X']])

# Yeah, I bring in a pre-built geojson containing my grid, because that is what `geobinning` ingests 
grid = gpd.read_file('./hexgrid.json')

gridBlocks = grid['geometry']

# Make the call to geobinning
# based on https://pypi.org/project/geobinning/

polygons = []
for gridBlocks in gridBlocks:
  lng,lat = gridBlocks.exterior.coords.xy
  lng= list(lng)
  lat= list(lat)
  coords = list(map(list,zip(*[lng,lat])))
  polygons.append(coords)

binCountLookup = gb.geobin(polygons, points)


####
# Okay not sure what to do now. 
# First, the resulting `binCountLookup` is all zeros. 
# Second, I don't know how to join the tables. It's probably just one simple function call, right?
####
```

##### data.csv sample

```
REQUEST_ID,CREATED_ON,Y,X
62946,2016-04-18T15:23:00,40.414919,-79.949436
137829,2017-03-08T10:24:00,40.413857,-79.949049
137655,2017-03-08T08:20:00,40.414341,-79.949477
72775,2016-05-24T18:23:00,40.412456,-79.949367
201777,2017-12-05T16:29:00,40.411797,-79.949422
201223,2017-12-01T09:30:00,40.411947,-79.949487
```

##### hexgrid.json sample

```json
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [-79.94868393697234, 40.41183792453613],
            [-79.94897928535387, 40.41222734167669],
            [-79.94956998211696, 40.41222734167669],
            [-79.94986533049848, 40.41183792453613],
            [-79.94956998211696, 40.41144850739557],
            [-79.94897928535387, 40.41144850739557],
            [-79.94868393697234, 40.41183792453613]
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [-79.94868393697234, 40.41261675881726],
            [-79.94897928535387, 40.41300617595782],
            [-79.94956998211696, 40.41300617595782],
            [-79.94986533049848, 40.41261675881726],
            [-79.94956998211696, 40.4122273416767],
            [-79.94897928535387, 40.4122273416767],
            [-79.94868393697234, 40.41261675881726]
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [-79.94868393697234, 40.41339559309838],
            [-79.94897928535387, 40.41378501023894],
            [-79.94956998211696, 40.41378501023894],
            [-79.94986533049848, 40.41339559309838],
            [-79.94956998211696, 40.41300617595782],
            [-79.94897928535387, 40.41300617595782],
            [-79.94868393697234, 40.41339559309838]
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [-79.94868393697234, 40.41417442737951],
            [-79.94897928535387, 40.41456384452007],
            [-79.94956998211696, 40.41456384452007],
            [-79.94986533049848, 40.41417442737951],
            [-79.94956998211696, 40.413785010238946],
            [-79.94897928535387, 40.413785010238946],
            [-79.94868393697234, 40.41417442737951]
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [-79.94868393697234, 40.414953261660635],
            [-79.94897928535387, 40.415342678801196],
            [-79.94956998211696, 40.415342678801196],
            [-79.94986533049848, 40.414953261660635],
            [-79.94956998211696, 40.414563844520075],
            [-79.94897928535387, 40.414563844520075],
            [-79.94868393697234, 40.414953261660635]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
    
  ]
}
```

Thank you so much for considering this question!

Comment: The grid elements are polygons with how many sides? Or are they classic "squares" of 10°?

Comment: Grid elements are polygons of 6 sides.

Comment: Do you want to count bins from the origin to the coordinates in the most optimal path? Or do you want to count all the bins like a square from the origin to the coordinates?